# Given a string formed only with 4 different letters, how many permutations of it exist with no two consecutive letters?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

Given a string *S*, formed with the letters *A, B, C, D*, each occurring at most *10* times in *S*
How many permutations of *S* do not contain *2* consecutive letters?

For example given

```
A: 3 times, B: 1 time, C: 1, D: 0

ABACA is valid
AABAC is invalid
```

I've tried inclusion exclusion but my model haven't been able to produce a good set of properties to use the principle.

Is there a formula or am I missing something?

Comment: I would say  (from [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination))`C(na, nb) * C(na + nb, nc) * C(na + nb + nc, nd)` (and extra condition to handle that `na >= 1+nb+nc+nd`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's dynamic programming

Creating each permutation from the scratch, so you are adding a letter at a time at the end of the string
Suppose you just have used letter 'A', the next letter can't be 'A', and you have 1 letter 'A' less than before, So you continue with this process until you run out of letters

Let be

```
f(prohibited, A, B, C, D)
```

the amount of strings of size *A + B + C + D*, which can be formed using *A* letters 'A', *B* letters 'B', ... and this strings cannot start with prohibited

Suppose prohibited equals 'A', so you have 3 options to choose from:

Start with letter 'B', then, next time, prohibited is 'B' and you have *B - 1* letters 'B', that is

```
f('B', A, B - 1, C, D)
```

if you had chosen 'C' instead of 'B', then prohibited is 'C' and you have C - 1 letter reamining

so do the sum

```
f('A', A - 1, B, C, D) + f('B', A, B - 1, C, D) ...
```

and that should do it.

Comment: A good approach. Note that memoization can be useful to avoid redundant calculations